# Ternary operator with constant variable in return statement. return a>b?a:b + 1; or return 1 + a>b?a:b;

Tags: java, return, operator-keyword, ternary

```
public static int test(){
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;      
        return a>b?a:b + 1;
}
```

The result is 1.

```
public static int test(){
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;      
        return 1 + a>b?a:b;
}
```

The result is 0.

HOW COMES??????

**EDIT**
I fixed error in code samples.

Comment: How comes that the exact same method gives two different results? This is a mistery to God too!

Answer (score 2):

In `return a>b?a:b + 1`, `a>b?a:b` is evaluated first; since `a` is not greater than `b`, it returns the value of `b + 1` , which is 1.

In `return 1 + a>b?a:b`, the compiler treats the condition as `(1 + a) > b`. Since it's true, it returns the value of `a`, which is 0.

Answer (score 1):

This is the result of the order of operations in Java. Review this [Java Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) post for a listing of operator precedence.

The first statement evaluates like this:

```
=> a > b ? a : b + 1
-> 0 > 0 ? 0 : (0 + 1) 
// 0 is not greater than 0 therefore return 'b+1' which is 1
-> 1
```

Your second statement evaluates like this:

```
=> 1 + a > b ? a : b
-> (1 + a) > b ? a : b
-> (1 + 0) > 0 ? 0 : 0
// 1 is greater than zero therefore return 'a' which is 0
-> 0
```

For the second statement, the "additive" operation `1 + a` takes precedence over the "relational" operation `> b`.

Again, read the Java Operators link above for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the illustration! Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the title of the question, apparently one of the two `test()` methods should read

```
public static int test(){
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;      
        return 1+a>b?a:b;
}
```

In such a case, given also that `a` and `b` are set to `0`, the result will always be `a` (i.e., `0`), irrespective of the last term (i.e., even if it were not `b` but `b + 1` or anything else).

Obviously, `1 + a = 1 + 0 = 1` and `1 > a`, so the result is `a`, i.e. `0`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!!

Answer (score 0):

You probably think that

```
return a>b?a:b + 1;
```

is equivalent of

```
return (a>b?a:b) + 1;
```

but it isn't. It is equivalent of

```
return a>b?a:(b + 1);
```

Same problem with

```
return 1 + a>b?a:b;
```

it is in fact

```
return (1 + a)>b?a:b;
```